# Conditional logic in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
mysql> desc mlb_lineups;
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| player_id            | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| team_id              | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| game_id              | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| gamedate             | date         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pos                  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_home              | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| is_pitcher           | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| opponent_team_id     | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| first_name           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| position             | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| hand_throws_with     | varchar(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

In order for me to retrieve a lineup that a team used last, let's say a team with `team_id` 31 in this case, I'd run the following query:

```
select * from mlb_lineups 
  where team_id = 31 
  and pos > -1 
  order by gamedate DESC,
  pos ASC LIMIT 9;
```

That works fine and dandy. What I'm trying to do though is a bit tricky and I can't seem to piece the way the inner query and/or conditional logic would work here. I want to run a query that basically says: retrieve a lineup that a team used last where the `opponent_team_id` had an `is_pitcher` equal to 1 with a `hand_throws_with` equal to L. `mlb_lineups` table will contain at least one row where a player `is_pitcher` is equal to `1` and `hand_throws_with` is equal to `L` where a team has a lefty throwing on the mound.

Essentially what I'd need to do to find out what the last lineup a `team_id` did used when their opposing pitcher had a hand_throws_with equal to `L` I'd have to run a query that would figure out what the last opponent_team_id they faced is with that particular handedness and then retrieve their lineup for that `game_id`. Does this schema provide enough information to run a single query for that? Did I provide enough information to make my problem understandable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you'll need to `JOIN` the table back to itself using the `opponent_team_id` and `game_id` fields.  There are a couple of ways to do this.

Here is one method using `EXISTS`:

```
  select * 
  from mlb_lineups ml1
  where tsn_team_id = 31 
     and pos > -1 
     and exists (
         select 1 
         from mlb_lineups ml2
         where ml1.opponent_team_id = ml2.team_id
            and ml2.is_pitcher = 1 
            and ml2.hand_throws_with = 'L'
            and ml1.game_id = ml2.game_id
     )
  order by gamedate desc, pos 
  limit 9;
```

This method uses a standard `JOIN` but it may require `DISTINCT`, depends on the data:

```
  select ml1.* 
  from mlb_lineups ml1
      inner join mlb_lineups ml2 on ml1.game_id = ml2.game_id
           and ml1.team_id = ml2.opponent_team_id
           and ml2.is_pitcher = 1 
           and ml2.hand_throws_with = 'L'
  where ml1.tsn_team_id = 31 
     and ml1.pos > -1 
  order by ml1.gamedate desc, ml1.pos 
  limit 9;
```